# Eclipse deploy/debug web application extension on Tomcat (i.e. Alfresco)

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, deployment, alfresco, remote-debugging

I'm using Eclipse and Tomcat do develop web applications extensions over Alfresco.
It means that my `tomcat webapps` folder looks like:

```
drwxr-xr-x 15 svil01 users      4096 25 feb 09:54 alfresco
-rw-r--r--  1 svil01 users 142241824 25 feb 09:54 alfresco.war
drwxr-xr-x 12 svil01 users      4096 25 feb 09:56 share
-rw-r--r--  1 svil01 users  27755504 25 feb 09:54 share.war
...
```

I have an eclipse project (call it `PrjExt`), in which there are
some java classes, and some jsp, they are extensions to alfresco,
so those should go for instance to:

```
TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes
TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/alfresco/
```

I know Alfresco asks to put them in AMP files,
but this is not feasible or efficient at developement stage.

There should be a way to hot deploy and debug from eclipse, as WTP plugin do.
The problem is that WTP deployment assembly mapping use a document base directory,
and it will publish to:

```
TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/PrjExt/
```

Eventually, changing project name it will publish to alfresco, but not incrementally, 
it will just erase the original alfresco content, which is not in my project.

I'm looking for an automatic refresh by Eclipse on java sources change, or resource change,
along with server refresh and debug feature.

Is there a way to do this without putting in my each extension project all the
Alfresco webapp source code and resources?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Ant build tools** to deploy your extension project into alfresco folder. (`TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes,TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/alfresco/`)

- In this way, you do not need to your extension project to be same
  name as alfresco.
- Do not erase any files under alfresco folder.

Example extension project can be found [here](http://ecmarchitect.com/images/articles/alfresco-people/someco-people.zip). The only two files you need to see is **build.xml** and **build.properties** file.

build.properties locates which location your want to deploy your extension project.
I hope this may help you.